# How do open source libraries like Apache Commons fit into the microservices architecture?

Tags: open-source, microservices, third-party-libraries

I'm reading about microservices, and one point I come across repeatedly, is, in order to achieve full indepencency, it's a bad idea to share libraries among microservices. Examples are [here](https://blog.philipphauer.de/dont-share-libraries-among-microservices/) and [here](https://runnable.com/blog/libraries-we-use-when-building-microservices).

But how do **open source libraries** fit into this image? Can I use Apache Commons or Guava? If I'm using Apache Commons Lang in multiple services, would that mean I create dependencies, opposing the aim of a microservices architecture to create independent services?

Comment: Sharing dependency is bad if that means that when you change that dependency, you have to update multiple services. If you use a general purpose library, it doesn't matter if one microservice uses version 1 and another uses version 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's about libraries created by **you** to share common functionality when you're trying to avoid rewriting the same code in your multiple microservices. It creates a situation where you have a (loose) dependency between the microservices through the shared library.

This can create problems such as needing to modify the shared library to satisfy a requirement for one microservice, whereas the other microservice will not expect this new functionality and may break.

It has nothing to do with using third party libraries in your microservices.